# Python: copy file to clipboard

Tags: python, file, copy, clipboard

I need a way to copy a PNG image with its known path to the windows clipboard. My program has a list of files, when one is selected a button is pressed and the file should be copied in the clipboard and allow for pasting somewhere else.

All I found online deals with images, by copying the image itself to the clipboard so it can be pasted in a chat or in paint. However, I couldn't find anything that allows me to copy **the file itself**, NOT its content, to the clipboard.

The idea would be to have a function that accepts a filepath as input and adds that file to the clipboard.

Note: I have also tried reading through [this (win32clipboard)](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/win32clipboard__SetClipboardData_meth.html) but have not been able to understand it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it, the solution was by using [PYQT](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/):

```python
data = QtCore.QMimeData()
url = QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile('C:\\path\\to\\image.png')
data.setUrls([url])
app.clipboard().setMimeData(data)
```